# Get all +ve number count in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am using the following thing:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0};
int x = a.Select(b => b != 0).Count();
```

I am getting **6** as the value, how can I get **4** instead of **6**.

Can someone please guid me.

Comment: a.Select() will select the result of `b => b != 0` for every element in your array (true / false). Whereas Where() will return only the elements in your array matching `b => b != 0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0}; 
int x = a.Where(b => b != 0).Count();
```

Comment: what is the difference between Select() and Where() can you please tell me. It might look silly but as I am a newbie :)

Comment: @DeviprasadDas Where filters, select projects.  Where will change the quantity of items in the sequence, select changes each item, so in your code it changes each item to a bool and sets the value to true or false based on your condition.

Comment: @DeviprasadDas see my edit i hope it will clarifies the difference between select and where ......

Comment: Select takes Func<TSource,TResult>(and other overloads) delegate as input parameter, wherein each element from source of type TSource will be projected into a form of type TResult. On the other hand, Where takes Func<TSource,bool> as parameter, wherein it will return true/false corresponding to each source element. In your case you are checking a boolean condition corresponding to each input integer element.

Answer (score 7):

Others have suggested using `Where` followed by `Count`, but you can do it even more simply:

```
int x = a.Count(b => b != 0);
```

This [overload of `Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) takes a predicate, and basically only counts the elements of the source sequence which match the predicate.

As others have noted, the reason it doesn't work for `Select` is that that just *projects* - it doesn't *filter*. You *could* use:

```
// Works but is horrible...
int x = a.Select(b => b != 0).Count(z => z);
```

... but I'd *really* suggest you don't.

Note that none of this does what your *title* talks about, which is finding *positive* values. For that, you'd want:

```
int x = a.Count(b => b > 0);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `Where`.

```
 int x = a.Where(b => b != 0).Count();
```

The [Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

Answer (score 3):

change this line

```
 int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0}; 
 int x = a.Select(b => b != 0).Count();
```

to

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0}; 
int x = a.Where(b => b != 0).Count();
```

Differnce between

**Where**

finds items that match and only returns those that do.

-> `IEnumerable<A>` in, `IEnumerable<A>` out

**Select**

returns something for *all* items in the source.  That something might be the items themselves, but are more usually a projection of some sort.

-> `IEnumerable<A>` in, `IEnumerable<B>` out

Answer (score 2):

Your code is just projecting the collection to bools and you get true where the value is not 0 and false where it is, to filer user where

e.g.

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0};
int x = a.Where(b => b != 0).Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is that `{1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0}.Select(b => b != 0)` is just `{true, true, true, false, true, false}`, which is again 6 items. You can better do with `Where` instead, which would give you the filtered sequence: `{1, 2, 3, 5}`. For the resulting sequence you can apply `Count` or whatever.